# Problemas de fuente - PHP

Tags: html, css

estoy realizando un pequeño sistema, en el cual en la parte de los usuarios agregue una Modal para agregar los mismos, el problema es que me cambia la fuente, por ejemplo asi es mi fuente normal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el cual este es el código de todas las librerías

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>Inicio</title>
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
```

Y cuando le doy a la pestaña Usuarios que es donde tengo la Modal, me cambia la fuente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me hace la fuente muy pequeña, las librerias que tengo en esta pagina son:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>Usuarios</title>
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>         
        <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

No se si mas de alguna me estará haciendo conflicto

Comment: puedes indicar dentro de las imágenes cual es la fuente que no es del tamaño correcto y tambien puedes mostrarnos que etilo tiene aplicado para la fuente cada una de las dos versiones?

Comment: La primera imagen es la que contiene el tamaño correcto, la segunda imagen que es donde tengo la Modal y es donde me cambia la fuente, no se cual libreria me estara realizando el conflicto y si quito alguna la Modal no me funciona

Comment: el datatables que estas usando es para BS4 y tu BS es ver 3

Comment: pero te darias cuenta en el inspector de codigo ... en la seccion de estilos

Comment: cual estilo se esta aplicando al elemento selecionado ...

Comment: y selecionas el que dices que tiene un layout distinto de lo esperado